# React testing-library not testing component containing <Link/> react router dom V6

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library

I am trying to write units tests for this component

```
const HomepageVideos = ({ place, close }) => {

    return (
        <>

            <Button className="mt-2 ms-2 close" onClick={close}>Start Over</Button>
            <div className="video text-center">
                <video autoPlay muted loop className='mt-3 video' data-testid="video">
                    {place === 'Dubai-UAE' ?
                        <source src='dubai.mp4' type="video/mp4" /> :
                        place === 'Kotor-MONTENEGRO' ?
                            <source src='kotor.mp4' type="video/mp4" /> :
                            <source src='tel-aviv.mp4' type="video/mp4" />
                    }
                </video>
                <h1>{place}</h1>

                
                <Link to="/flights" state={{ place }}>
                    <Button className="bg-warning text-dark mt-2">Flights to {place}</Button>
                </Link>


            </div>

        </>
    );
}
```

However, any test I write returns the following error message :

> console.error
> Error: Uncaught [TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'basename' of 'React__namespace.useContext(...)' as it is null.]

I think this error is related to the use of a `<Link/>` in the component HomepageVideos. There is no specific path to this component as it is part of another component `<HomeForm/>`, itself included in the parent `<Homepage/>`. I have wrapped the app in a `<Router/>`in the index.js. The functionality works fine but I can't seem to write any test. What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Link` component from `react-router` has to be inside a router for it to work. You can use a `MemoryRouter` to test your component.

```
const mockClose = jest.fn();
describe('tests the HomePageVideos component', () => {
  it('renders the component', async () => {
    const routes = [
      {
        path: '/test',
        element: <HomePageVideos place="Dubai-UAE" close={mockClose} />,
      },
    ];

    const router = createMemoryRouter(routes, {
      initialEntries: ['/test'],
      initialIndex: 0,
    });

    render(<RouterProvider router={router} />);

    expect(screen.getByRole('link')).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
});
```